# Can someone give me a hint for creating a splash effect for my game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

First off ,I'm so sorry for my bad(may be very bad) English.:o
I am in middle of building a painting game which you can create a picture by throw the paint balloons to a wall or something like that.But i have no clue how to create the paint splash effect when the balloon pop and also how to keep the paint stains which shoot on the wall either.i am using cocos2d for my game.
I hope someone can give a hint to solve my question.I don't know how to express my expectation in English but i really do:p.Please help me with my little game :D .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Physics for Game Developers](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000066) book.

Especially at chapters dedicated to 2D/3D-particle kinematics and collisions.